# Group date by week number in the form YYYY-MM-WW

Tags: postgresql

Currently have rows aggregated by week number.

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'IYYY-MM-IW') AS week, from TABLE GROUP BY week
```

The results will show the form "2021-07-29". Is it possible to change the week number such that it is the number week of the month (instead of year).

For example, instead of "2021-07-29", we convert to "2021-07-04" since the 29th week of the year is actually the 4th week of the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)

> `W`   week of month (1–5) (the first week starts on the first day of the month)

So you can use:

```
to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-W')
```

For e.g 2021-10-18 this yields `2021-10-3` (third week in October)